# Get balance by address

Tags: nodeos, rpc

Which endpoint can return me balance and full transaction history by given parameter address. Accordingly to this documentation [RPC documentation](https://eosio.github.io/eos/group__eosiorpc.html#v1chaingetaccount) I need to have account name. Or how can i start FUll node of eos, like some explorer etc?

Answer (score 3):

To get transaction history, you need to hit a node that has that filter installed (otherwise you'll get back an empty array). Here's a working curl request (replace accountnamehere with a real account name):

```
curl --request POST \
 --url http://api.eosnewyork.io/v1/history/get_actions \
 --data '{"account_name":"accountnamehere","pos":0,"offset":200}'
```

Not sure how to get balance yet, but it should be from hitting the `/v1/chain/get_currency_balance` endpoint with an HTTP POST request:
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_currency_balance

Comment: To get balance: `curl --request POST \
  --url http://api.eosnewyork.io/v1/chain/get_currency_balance \
  --data '{"code":"eosio.token","account":"ACCOUNTNAMEHERE","symbol":"EOS"}'`

Answer (score 3):

Query your account name by publick key

```
cleos -u https://mainnet.meet.one get accounts *publick_key*
```

Query your balance by account name

```
cleos -u https://mainnet.meet.one get currency balance eosio.token *account_name*
```

Query your account info(CPU/NET/RAM) by account name

```
cleos -u https://mainnet.meet.one get account *account_name*
```

Query your refunding amount

```
cleos -u https://mainnet.meet.one get table eosio *account_name* refunds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an EOS account name via the EOS Public key associated with it using a Block Explorer like [EOSTracker](https://eostracker.io/)

If you prefer to do it on cleos, you can use this command. 
`cleos get accounts *Public key*`

It would be overkill to create your own node to sync with the chain just to check your balance but it is possible.

Comment: I like this one : http://eosflare.io/

Answer (score 0):

To get transaction history you need to query a full node with filter option on. Most top BPs have this option on. You can use our node for example: https://api.eosargentina.io:8888

To get transactions you need to type this command:

```
cleos -u https://api.eosargentina.io:8888 get actions YOURACCOUNT
```

To get balance you can do:

```
cleos -u https://api.eosargentina.io:8888 get currency balance eosio.token YOURACCOUNT eos
```